# How to split a dataframe column into two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Im looking to see how to split a single data frame column into two columns and replace a symbol for another. For example, if the data frame y has;

| X1 |
| --- |
| NA |
| 1/0:0.82 |
| 1/1:1.995 |
| 0/1:1.146 |
| NA |
| 1/1:1.995 |

I want to be able to split the data into two columns like so and substitute the "/" symbol for a".".

| X1 | X2 |
| --- | --- |
| NA |  |
| 1.0 | 0.82 |
| 1.1 | 1.995 |
| 0.1 | 1.146 |
| NA |  |
| 1.1 | 1.995 |

Whenever I try to use str.split I keep running into errors. Any help would e great.

Edit:

X1

---

NA

1|0:0.82

1|1:1.995

0|1:1.146

NA

1|1:1.995

How to separate it so its
|X1|X2|
|--|--|
|NA|
|1/0|0.82|
etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
read.table(text=df$X1, sep=':', fill=T, h=F, dec = '/')
   V1    V2
1  NA      
2 1.0  0.82
3 1.1 1.995
4 0.1 1.146
5  NA      
6 1.1 1.995
```

If you want columns in respective data.types:

```
type.convert(read.table(text=df$X1, sep=':', fill=T, h=F, dec = '/'), as.is = TRUE)
   V1    V2
1  NA    NA
2 1.0 0.820
3 1.1 1.995
4 0.1 1.146
5  NA    NA
6 1.1 1.995
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, "1/0:0.82", "1/1:1.995", "0/1:1.146", NA,
                 "1/1:1.995")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, if I wanted to convert it the "/" to something other than "." like "<" how could I edit your code?

Comment: @RobertS - I don't think you can directly fix it with a faux-decimal point like Onyambu has done. You'd have to fix it afterwards using `sub("/", "<", output$V1)` or similar

Comment: @RobertS my output does not have a `.` that is a decimal. So you just use the format function. ie `format(output$V1, dec = '<')`

Comment: @thelatemail note that my output does not contain `/`

Comment: Cool, because I have another file where the numbers are separated by a "|" and Im looking to change that to a "/" symbol but I keep running into problems where the "/" is added before the number.(i.e. I keep getting "/1|0" instead of "1/0")

Comment: @RobertS in that case use `sub` function. ie the number `1|0` is technically not a number but a string. thus use `sub('|', '/', your_string, fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: So would I pipe them together, when I try to run them separately I get a huge mass of a  dataframe with no seperation. I guess if Im trying to do the same thing as before and separate them into two columns (but the first values have a "|" between them instead of a "/"). and I want to change those "|" into "/". How would I go and do that, sorry I'm very new to R.

Comment: @RobertS I do not understand your question. Please include an example in the question

Comment: Sorry, I added an edit to the original post on the bottom

Comment: @RobertS use the same code, but instead of `/` use, `|`

Comment: If I do df<-read.table(text=df$v19, sep=':', fill=T, h=F, dec = '|') it still leaves me with 1.0 and 1.1 instead of 1/0 and 1/1

Comment: @RobertS It seems you are going back and forth. Okay. Once you have the `df` after running the code above, do `transform(df, V1 = format(V1, dec = '/'))`

Comment: I just cleared my environment and redid the code and the "|" are still remaining                  df <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, "1|0:0.82", "1|1:1.995", "0|1:1.146", NA,
                            "1|1:1.995")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2<-read.table(text=df$X1, sep=':', fill=T, h=F, dec = '/')
df3<-transform(df2, V1 = format(V1, dec = '/'))

Comment: @RobertS because you did not change `df2` ie `df2<-read.table(text=df$X1, sep=':', fill=T, h=F, dec = '|')`

Comment: @Onyambu , I didnt change df2?

Comment: @RobertS the `dec = '|'` was the one you wanted when running `df2`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `separate` to split data on `:` into two columns and replace `/` to `.` in the first column. Using data from @Onyambu -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
  separate(X1, c('X1', 'X2'), sep = ':') %>%
  mutate(X1 = sub('/', '.', X1)) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

df

#   X1    X2
#1  NA    NA
#2 1.0 0.820
#3 1.1 1.995
#4 0.1 1.146
#5  NA    NA
#6 1.1 1.995
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit`

```
d$d
[1] NA          "1/0:0.82"  "1/1:1.995" "0/1:1.146" NA          "1/1:1.995"

data.frame( unname( t(data.frame( strsplit(sub("/",".",d$d), ":") )) ) )
    X1    X2
1 <NA>  <NA>
2  1.0  0.82
3  1.1 1.995
4  0.1 1.146
5 <NA>  <NA>
6  1.1 1.995
```

##### Data

```
d <- structure(list(d = c(NA, "1/0:0.82", "1/1:1.995", "0/1:1.146",
NA, "1/1:1.995")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

EDIT, For any other substitution use:

```
d$d
[1] NA          "1|0:0.82"  "1|1:1.995" "0|1:1.146" NA          "1|1:1.995"

data.frame( unname( t(data.frame( strsplit(sub("\\|","/",d$d), ":") )) ) )
    X1    X2
1 <NA>  <NA>
2  1/0  0.82
3  1/1 1.995
4  0/1 1.146
5 <NA>  <NA>
6  1/1 1.995
```